# PHP / MySQL generate table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I need to generate html table based on information from database(mysql) using PHP. Problem is that i don't know how much columns and rows that table have(user can add columns and rows). I don't know how to select specific row 'type'. I have table options, options_cats(options categories). It's easy when you know how much columns you have, but what to do when you don't know? :)

Example:

```
 Size | Color | -> this will be column names(user can add many as he want), it's selected from options_cats table, column 'name'.
```

Now i need to select options by type(ex. size, color..) and put it in correct column.

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              @foreach($ops as $op)
              <th>{{$op->title}}</th>
              @endforeach
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            @foreach($ops as $op)
            <tr>
              @foreach($op->options as $option)
              <td>{{$option->name}}</td>
              @endforeach
            </tr>
            @endforeach

          </tbody>
</table>
```

$ops ->

```
public function options($prod_id) {
        $data = array();
        $cats = DB::table('options_cats')->where('prod_id', $prod_id)->get();

        foreach ($cats as $cat) {
            $cat->options = DB::table('options')->where('category', $cat->id)
                                                 ->where('prod_id', $cat->prod_id)->get();
            $data[] = $cat;
        }

        return $data;   



    }
```

But now result is:

```
Paper size  Orientation 
A4          A3          
Landscape   Portrait
```

I will put column 'type' after i realize how to make this.

**EDIT:**
I have one page in administration where i can add options and categories for that options, when i add new category option(paper size ex.), there will be input where you can add option         for paper size, ex. A4(you can add many as you want), if i add color option category for ex. than you will need to enter paper size and color for option that you adding. I hope that you understand now :)

Comment: if you just whant to know the columns of a table check the schema: with something like this: `select column_name from schema.columns where TABLE_NAME = <table_name>`.

Comment: Table columns are generated by row, row 'name' from options_cats table are column name.

Comment: sorry then, I think I do not quite understand what you want to do. please add some sample data and operation

Comment: OP says that the table `options_cats` has option categories under the column `name` with values like `size`, `color`, etc. And OP wants them as a pivot result.

Comment: Where/What is this `type` column you're talking about? Also in your `options_cats` table?

Comment: It's not added yet, but it will be like this: when you adding new option you can choose 'type' of that option. If i add option A4, and set 'type' as paper size, that option need to be listed in paper size column. I will make function that will select options by type, but how to know what is type of column where it needs to display(ID for example).

Answer (score 1):

This is one way of generating a table with variable number of columns:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>Type</tr>

        <tr>
            @foreach($rows[0]['columns'] as $columns)
                <th>{{$columns['title'])}}</th>
            @endforeach
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach($rows as $row)
            <tr>
              <td>$rows['type']</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                @foreach($row['columns'] as $column)
                    <td>{{$column['value']}}</td>
                @endforeach
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

To use this very same code you'll have to generate an array with your data like this one:

```
$rows = array( 
                array(    
                        'type' => 'Car',

                        'columns' => array(
                                                array('title' => 'Color', 'value' => 'Blue'),
                                                array('title' => 'Size', 'value' => '10'),
                                            ),

                                     array(
                                                array('title' => 'Color', 'value' => 'Red'),
                                                array('title' => 'Size', 'value' => '11'),
                                            ),
                    ),

                array(    
                        'type' => 'Paper',

                        'columns' => array(
                                                array('title' => 'Color', 'value' => 'Blue'),
                                                array('title' => 'Size', 'value' => '10'),
                                            ),

                                     array(
                                                array('title' => 'Color', 'value' => 'Red'),
                                                array('title' => 'Size', 'value' => '11'),
                                            ),
                    ),

            );
```

**EDIT**

You posted your code while I was writing my answer and your table looks very like mine, even the class is the same, it's just you're using collections and I'm using arrays.

**EDIT 2**

Looks like you are in need to swap columns and rows. So you have some options:

1) Generate, via SQL, an already inverted result set. Since the number of columns is unknwown, you might have to deal with dynamic SQL, this is an example in MySQL

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT('MAX(CASE WHEN b.Race_Number = ', Race_Number,
      ' THEN b.Place END) AS ', CONCAT('`Race', Race_Number, '`'))
    ) INTO @sql
FROM Table2;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT s.Student_name, ', @sql, ' 
                   FROM Table1 a
                   LEFT JOIN Table2 b 
                        ON ON a.ID = b.ID
                   GROUP   BY a.ID, a.Name');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

2) Add some more code to `options()` to generate an array with your result. Basically you have to read all your columns and make them rows.

3) Use Javascript to swap them at run time.

Comment: When you adding new option, you adding all columns. For example, if there is column size, color, than you need to add both, you can't add only one. One row one option with names of size, color etc. for ex.

Comment: Oh! You have a variable number of columns per row? One row with two columns and another with three?

Comment: No :) One row with same number of columns, if you add option categories ex. color and size, than, when you adding new option you need to put size and color, nothing more and nothing less. I will edit my question and put what i want, it's easier than this.

Comment: Ok. I think I got now. Edited to give you some answer, that might not help you directly, but can put you in the right track.

Comment: Thanks for help, i will try to make something :)